# HTML5 multi canvas fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making html5 game. It use several canvases.

```
<div id="GameContainer" >
<canvas id="MapCanvas" width="1200" height="690" style=" position:absolute;z-index: 1s; ">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
<canvas id="CellHighLightCanvas"width="1200" height="690" style=" position:absolute;z-index: 2;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>

<canvas id="UnderUnitCanvas" width="1200" height="690" style="position:absolute;  z-index: 3;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
```

I trying make full screen. I used this method:

```
if (element.requestFullScreen)
            element.requestFullScreen();
        else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen)
            element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen)
            element.mozRequestFullScreen();
```

Where element is each from canvases(this code inside loop).But it works only for 1 canvas. How can i do this for all canvases?

Comment: @ComFreek element is each from canvases(this code inside loop)

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand your question - how exactly do you propose that any of the canvases would be 'full-screen' if you are trying to display several of them 'full-screen' at once? Something is full-screen or it isn't. There can be no sharing - two items cannot be made full-screen at once. If they could, they'd each be 'half-screen'... (see the contradiction in the definition of 'full-screen' and your request?) You can make a page or an iframe full-screen - each of which may contain several canvas elements.

Comment: I hoped that it can be several elements "full screen". Thanks for info

Answer (score 1):

You can't have more than one element fullscreen at once. Use the parent div:

```
var element = document.getElementById("GameContainer");

if (element.requestFullScreen)
  element.requestFullScreen();
else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen)
  element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen)
  element.mozRequestFullScreen();
```

Comment: I tryed this variant before ask a question. But as you see each canvas has fixed size. and if  i will set fullscreen of "GameContainer". it will enlarge only div, not canvases. if I set canvases width and height to 100%. they will be too large because their position is  absolute.

Comment: You'll have to redo your css, because the above is the only way to do it.